# Difference between rows of different variables, avoiding macro method

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to find the average time between two processes. Each record is a repair process with an part ID, a start date, and an end date. For a given ID, only one repair process can occur at a time. See sample data below:

```
ID  START_DATE  END_DATE
123  1/2/2006   2/3/2006
124  1/3/2006   4/2/2006
123  3/5/2006   3/7/2006
123  6/2/2006   6/4/2006
123  6/8/2006   6/9/2006
124  6/2/2006   6/4/2006
124  6/5/2006   6/9/2006
124  6/10/2006   6/12/2006
```

The information I need is the difference between the END_DATE and START_DATE for a given ID. For example, for ID 123, the time between its first process and the second process is 3/5/2006 - 2/3/2006. If the list were longer, I would then take the all those differences and take the average of them.

The output would be something like this:

```
ID  AverageTime
123   4.3
124   2.3
```

My approach is to create a macro based on the following steps:

1. Create list of unique IDs.
2. For each ID in list, create table
   of just that ID.
3. Calculate the difference between START_DATE and
   END_DATE for that ID using the LAG function.
4. Average the
   difference and append to list of unique IDs.

I think this would work, but may take a long time because there are 400k rows. Is there a way to do this without a macro? How might this process be optimized as the server I am running this on is very slow?

Comment: You don't need a macro. Show what you want as output and a larger input set. This is at most a simple data step and PROC MEANs or a single SQL query.

Comment: And 400K records is trivial these days, you should be able to process this is less than a minute on your server.

Comment: And do you mean the third and first process? Your date references don't seem correct.

Comment: @Reeza. Updated the question. Also, by first and second I mean first and second for that ID.

Comment: *For example, for ID 123, the time between its first process and the second process is 3/5/2006 - 2/3/2006.* Why is the first process not the first record? Why do you skip that second record and jump to the third?

Comment: And are your dates mmddyy or ddmmyy?

Comment: @Reeza Dates are are ddmmmyy. It's skipped because it's sorted by date, not by ID. I could sort by ID to make it first and second record but the general question remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a data step and a PROC MEANS. 
Use LAG() to find the previous value. You cannot use DIF() here because you're looking at different variables.

```
data middle_step;
set have;
by id;

lag_end = lag(end_date);
duration = start_date-lag_end;

if first.id then duration=.;

run;

proc means data=middle_step mean;
class id;
var duration;
run;
```

Comment: I am going to try this, but doesn't this have some overlap on ID then, even if sorted? At the end of each section of each ID, this compares START_DATE for the next ID to the end date of the last ID, right?

Comment: Try it. `if first.id` resets it so that it is missing by default for the first record.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the "SAS-y" way of doing it.

First your data:

```
data have;
input ID  START_DATE  END_DATE;
informat start_date end_date mmddyy10.;
format start_date end_date mmddyy10.;
datalines;
123  1/2/2006   2/3/2006
124  1/3/2006   4/2/2006
123  3/5/2006   3/7/2006
123  6/2/2006   6/4/2006
123  6/8/2006   6/9/2006
124  6/2/2006   6/4/2006
124  6/5/2006   6/9/2006
124  6/10/2006   6/12/2006
;
```

Sort by the ID and Start_Date:

```
proc sort data=have;
by id start_date;
run;
```

Next add a record count for each id and a link to the previous one.

```
data tmp;
set have;
by id;
if first.id then 
    id_cnt = 0;

id_cnt + 1;
id_last = id_cnt-1;
run;
```

Then join the data to itself taking the mean of the difference between first end and next start:

```
proc sql noprint;
create table want as
select a.id
     , mean(b.start_date - a.end_date) as ave
    from tmp as a,
         tmp as b
    where a.id=b.id and 
          a.id_cnt=b.id_last
    group by a.id;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Working off Dom's input and sort, this DOW loop will compute each id's mean gap in a single pass:

```
... input ...
... sort ...

data want(keep=id gap_mean);
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;

    if prior_end then gap_sum = sum ( gap_sum, end_date - prior_end );
    prior_end = end_date;
  end;

  gap_mean = gap_sum / (_n_ - 1);  * number of gaps is the number of iterations less 1;
run;
```

Code items of note:

- `set` and `by` statement inside loop
- loop iterations tracked with `_n_` (convenience - reuse of automatic variable)
- `until (last.id)` loop test works because every by group has at least one row and flag is set at last row in group
- `gap_sum` computed with `sum()` so the first gap can accumulated cleanly.

  - Alternative `... then gap_sum = gap_sum + end_date-prior_end` works, but would cause the LOG to sho `NOTE: Missing values were generated as a result of performing an operation on missing values.`
  - Alternative `... then gap_sum + (end_date - prior_date)` works without the NOTE, but the `+` operator would cause `gap_sum` to be implicitly RETAINed, which means `gap_sum` would have to be explicitly reset before the `do`
- `prior_end` is a manual lag for next iter
- when a group is finished the mean is computed and implicitly output
- when implicit loop returns to top it will be the start of the next group.  Non-retained variables will get reset to missing (.) Those of importance are `gap_sum` and `prior_end`

Answer (score 0):

The calculation can also be done in a single SQL query:

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
    select id,mean(dif) as mean_dif from(
       select a.id,min(b.start_date-a.end_date) as dif
       from have a,have b
       where a.id=b.id
         and a.end_date<b.start_date
       group by a.id,a.start_date)
    group by id;
run;
```

But a datastep solution may run faster, if that matters.